# MKLocalSearch not returning expected result

Tags: ios, mapkit, mklocalsearch, mklocalsearchrequest

I am creating an iOS app and I have a requirement to create an appointment, similar to "Create Event" of the default Calendar app.

I have to fill a location field, which will specify the location of the appointment and I am using MKLocalSearchRequest/MKLocalSearch.

But, the output I am getting is quite different than what I get on the default Calendar app.

I would like to get the similar result of the Calendar app.

My question is - Why am I getting different result than that of Calendar app? and what should I do to get the similar result to Calendar app.

My code is pretty simple -

I have a view controller that has table view and it implements UISearchResultsUpdating

so that gives, user a search bar to type some text and based on that I perform MKLocalSearch and return the result.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    locations_name.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    locations_title.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    var searchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchController.searchBar.text

    var search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response : MKLocalSearchResponse! , error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if response == nil {
            return
        }
        for result in response.mapItems {
            let item = result as! MKMapItem                
            self.locations_name.append(item.name)
            self.locations_title.append(item.placemark.title)

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView!.reloadData()
        })
    }

}
```

Here are the images of default Calendar app location search and my app's search.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd love to know too. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I haven't done anything to improve the search results and I think as a developer we can't do anything.

Comment: @raghvendra : I face same issue after one year of your query, please help me if you solve this problem.

Comment: There is nothing to solve here, this is how it works.